# QTableView/QAbstractTableModel binding

Tags: qt

There are one example in $QTDIR\Examples\Qt-5.7\widgets\tutorials\modelview\2_formatting. the main.cpp is like this:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QTableView>
#include "mymodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableView tableView;
    MyModel myModel(0);
    tableView.setModel( &myModel );
    tableView.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I write a test program according to the example. the purpose is to add a tabwidget. and show the tabview in the tab with my own model. my code is like this:

```
//nsalarmmodel.h
#ifndef NSALARMMODEL_H
#define NSALARMMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class NSalarmModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    NSalarmModel(QObject *parent);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE ;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

};

//main.cpp
#include "nsalarmmodel.h"
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QTabWidget *tabWidget;
QGridLayout *gridLayout;

tabWidget = new QTabWidget;
QTabWidget *alarmTab = new QTabWidget;
QTableView *alarmForm = new QTableView(alarmTab);
tabWidget->addTab(alarmTab,"TEST");
gridLayout = new QGridLayout(alarmTab);
gridLayout->setSpacing(6);
gridLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
gridLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("gridLayout"));
gridLayout->addWidget(alarmForm, 0, 0, 1, 1);
tabWidget->show();

//QTableView tableView;
NSalarmModel alarmModel(0);
alarmForm->setModel( &alarmModel);

return a.exec();
}
```

and it can be successful to bind alamModel(QAbstractTableModel) to alarmForm(QTableview).

Then I changed my design. just show my contents in mainwindow UI. but I can't bind my model to the view successfully if I write in mainwindow.cpp just like:

```
NSalarmModel alarmModel(0);                (1)
alarmForm->setModel( &alarmModel);
```

I have to do like this to bind successfully:

```
NSalarmModel *alarmModel = new NSalarmModel(0);           (2)
alarmForm->setModel( alarmModel);
```

So my question is why the sentences (1) are not working well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (1) the model is allocated in the stack and is destroyed at the end of the code block. You have to allocate it in the heap as in (2).

See [The stack and the heap](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/)